# Having a problem getting a TestName and count from database, grouped

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by, count

I have 3 tables with the following column names and content

```
    TPatient:   ID      fPatientName
                1       John Smith
                2       Jane Doe
                3       Jane Smith
                4       John Doe
         
    tLabResults fPatientID  fLabTestID      |   tLabTestNames   ID      fTestName   
                1           2               |                   1       WBC 
                2           3               |                   2       Glucose   
                1           4               |                   3       RBC
                4           1               |                   4       Platelett
                4           6               |                   5       Hemoglobin
                1           2               |                   6       Sodium 
                1           6               |
```

When I select A Patient
I would like get the the LabTestNames, The number of times patient had that test

Selecting  John Smith, ID=1 I would like to get (alphabetical by Test Name

```
            Platelett   1    | he had 1 platelett test
            Sodium      1    | he had 1 sodium test
            WBC         2    | he had 2 WBC tests
```

I have tried some SQL statement with joins, etc. No luck. My latest:

```
SELECT
    tLabTestNames.fTestName,
    Count(tLabResults.fLabTest)
FROM
    tLabResults, tLabTestNames
WHERE  tlabresults.fpatient = 1
GROUP BY
    tLabResults.fLabTest
ORDER BY
    tLabTestNames.fTestName;
```

yields: Your query does not include the specified expression 'fTestName' as part of an aggregate function.

Any ideas on how I can get my desired result?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 community edition, with C# (windows forms), and OleDB connecting to an access database.

BTW I have only used SELECT fields, SELECT COUNT(*) and simple SQL queries (ie where X<7), never something that had multiple operations, so please be kind, and show an example if possible.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below.

```
SELECT p.fPatientName, tn.fTestName, COUNT(*)
FROM TPatient p
LEFT JOIN TLabResults lr ON lr.fPatientID = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN TLabTestNames tn ON tn.ID = lr.fLabTestID
GROUP BY p.fPatientName, tn.fTestName
ORDER BY p.fPatientName, tn.fTestName
```

Comment: Eric,

I tried your SQL

```
SELECT p.fPatientName, tn.fTestName, COUNT(*)
FROM tPatients p
LEFT JOIN tLabResults lr ON lr.fPatientID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN tLabTestNames tn ON tn.ID = lr.fLabTestID
GROUP BY p.fPatientName, tn.fTestName
ORDER BY p.fPatientName, tn.fTestName
```
I get:
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'lr.fPatientID = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN tLabTestNames tn ON tn.ID = lr.fLabTestI'.   <-- note missing D at the end

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with my query syntax wise.  You will need to confirm the column names since I don't have access to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work properly:

```
SELECT
    tLabTestNames.fTestName, count(tLabResults.fLabTestID) AS Results, tLabResults.fLabTestID
FROM
    tLabResults
INNER JOIN
    tLabTestNames
ON
    tLabTestNames.LabTestID=tLabResults.fLabTestID
WHERE
    tLabResults.fPatientID=1
GROUP BY
    fTestName,fLabTestID;
```

Note that some of the Field Or Table Names may have changed, but this shows the essence of what I needed.
the WHERE condition has the '1' for the patient id I am looking for, but it can be any patient ID